# Creating a 2D mesh with Meshpy

Tags: python

I want to build a 2D mesh with the Python Module Meshpy. Here is a simple Code for an example:

```
from meshpy.tet import MeshInfo, build

mesh_info = MeshInfo()
mesh_info.set_points([
    (0,0,0), (2,0,0), (2,2,0), (0,2,0),
    ])
mesh_info.set_facets([
    [0,1,2,3],
    ])
mesh = build(mesh_info)
```

How you can see its just a simple square in 2D. If i want to try to mesh it, Python crashes with the error Code "Exception:  All vertices are coplanar (Tol = 1e-08)".
Is there a possibility for creating meshes with Meshpy in 2D or does it only works in 3D?
And if its possible, can i change the size of the mesh?

Comment: I haven't used Meshpy before but check to see if using floating point values fixes things, i.e. `(0., 0., 0.)`. (I doubt it will since they do indeed seem coplanar.)

Comment: Try `meshpy.triangle`.

Comment: check the doc https://documen.tician.de/meshpy/, or google "meshpy examples"